# Struts 2 -Token issue

Tags: jsp, browser, struts2, refresh, token

I am trying to prevent multiple form submits caused by browser refresh by setting a use once only token in session and comparing it with request. However when I am trying to reset the session token, it is not getting updated. Below is my code.

Set Token which renders the jsp page

```
getSession().setAttribute(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY, "123");
```

This is in my jsp

```
  <s:hidden name="token" value="123"/>
```

Action class

```
String requestToken = getToken();
String sessionToken = (String)      
getRequest().getSession().getAttribute(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY);

 if(requestToken.equalsIgnoreCase(sessionToken)){
   //reset the token  
  getRequest().getSession().setAttribute(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY, "124");

   //perform update

 }
```

The session token is not getting updated to 124. Please assist.

Thanks,
Prasheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code in action.

In loading of previous page

```
 ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY, "123");
```

In jsp page

```
<s:hidden name="token" value="123"/>
```

And in action class of form submission

```
 Map<String,Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
     if(getToken().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(session.get(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY).toString())){
   System.out.println("request is handled");
       //reset the token
       //perform update
         session.put(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY, "124");
     }
```

In both jsp pages use this

```
< %
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
  response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
  response.setHeader("Vary", "*");
% >
```

The simple way is

```
if (session.getAttribute("recordInsertedSuccessfully") == null )
{
   //update records
   //after inserting into the database we should do :
   session.putAttribute("recordInsertedSuccessfully","true");
} else {
   //case of form re-submission
}
```

Your problem is you are again calling the method which is setting session variable to 123.

make another method `runinspect2()`, copy paste code from `runinspect()` but remove line from `runinspect2()` which is setting session variable to 123 which is following line

```
 ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY, "123");
```

and call `runinspect2()` in `update()` method it is simple

Comment: Thanks a lot Parth Trivedi. I tried as you mentioned but still when i refresh the page using F5, the value still is 123. Below is my code                                                               
         Method A(){
               ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY.toString(), "123");
        }

Comment: Method B(){
           if(getToken().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get            (Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY).toString())){
            ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY, "124");
        }

Comment: On my jsp page, there is a button and the user clicks on it and the form gets submitted, the user is clicking F5 continuously and the browser displays a message that the action will be done again but still the user does it again. This is causing multiple webservice calls and the same message gets displayed multiple times. I tried using a post redirect with the below code but the jsp doesnt get rendered correctly.

Comment: I tried using Post Redirect Get but I am not able to figure out why the page is not rendered properly. Please let me know if there is something i did incorrect over here.

My original code was

<action name="update-test" class="testAction" method="test">
<result name="success">/test/xyz/test-result.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="update-test" class="testAction" method="test">
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">forward-test</result>
</action>
<action name="forward-test" class="testAction" method="forward">
<result name="success">/test/xyz/test-result.jsp</result>
</action>

Comment: Below is the exception.
Apr 26, 2014 4:12:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jsp.portal.tiles.tickets.tests_002test_002dresult_002dv1_jsp._jspService(tests_002dtest_002dresult_002dv1_jsp.java:196)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

Comment: When I did a view source on Line 196, I see the below. Please help.
<div id="tabXYZ" class="panel">
<img src="/images/arrow_mainmenu.jpg" width="25" height="31" alt="" class="floatingleft">

Comment: okey.. actually when you refresh the page at that time session value is set to 123.. so when you refresh page multiple times it sets it 123 again and again.now when you submit method b is called and is checking if it is 123 and sets it to 124. Is this right or i misunderstood it? when method b is called? and when method a is called? please tell me.

Comment: When the jsp is rendered, method A is called, then on the jsp I have a button addmessage, clicking that submits the form method B is called, the user is clicking F5 and getting the message that the information will be resent but he is still clicking on F5 which is causing multiple messages to be added.

Comment: so you are checking if the hidden value is 123 only once it should be processed.. am I right? That is why you are checking it if it is 123?

Comment: you should add <s:hidden name="token" value="%{#session.get('org.apache.struts.action.TOKEN')}"/> in jsp page when it is loading

Comment: So I need to remove what I hardcoded  <s:hidden name="token" value="123"/>? What I want to achieve is when the user clicks on submit the form should be submitted once and if clicks on browser refresh (F5) it shouldn't submit the form over and over again.

Comment: Getting jsp error,  java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.jsp.portal.tiles.tickets.incidents_002dinspect_002dresult_002dv4_jsp._jspService

Comment: Added the below in my jsp <s:hidden name="token" value="%{#session.get('org.apache.struts.action.TOKEN')}"/>                             if(!getToken().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY).toString())){
            ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY, "124");

Comment: Hi Parth, Is there any other way  that I can refresh a webpage without browser asking to resend data again.  Browser displays this message "To display this page, Firrfox will repeat any action that was performed earlier" when the user clicks on F5 and the form gets submitted again.

Comment: I tried as mentioned but still when i press F5, the value is not resetting to 124.

Comment: Method A() {ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY, "123");}

Comment: Method B(){ap<String,Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
               if(getToken().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(session.get(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY).toString())){
                System.out.println("request is handled");
                session.put(Globals.TRANSACTION_TOKEN_KEY, "124");

Comment: The jsp which renders where I perform the action and  redirected to on success is the same jsp, I added this code< %
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
  response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
  response.setHeader("Vary", "*");
% >

Comment: Are your method A and method B in the same action?

Comment: They are in the same action class

Comment: Sure.I will install it in a few min.please provide u r id

Comment: I am unable to install team viewer on my client laptop :(..Can I email you the files if its not a problem with you?

Comment: you do not need to install it just select "run one time only" option. you can get my email id in my profile of stack overflow. use my gmail email id

Comment: I get access denied accessing that link itself. I will email the files to you in a few min. Really Appreciate all your help.

Comment: the problem is you are calling runinspect() at line no 514 in update() method, so it is again setting value of session variable to 123.

Comment: This has been the existing code. If I try to remove it it might cause issues I think

Comment: make another method runinspect2(), copy paste code from runinspect() but rempve line which is stting sessin var to 123 and call runinspect2() in update method it is simple :)

Comment: See this and accept answers of your questions by click on check button near answer in this page http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work